# How to step through workflow when using tmate to debug GitHub Actions

Tags: debugging, ssh, github-actions

I'm often debugging my GitHub Actions using tmate, so I have the  `mxschmitt/action-tmate@v3` step as the first step in my workflow file, and I can manually trigger it and ssh into the runner.

But once I'm on the runner, I want to step through the bits of my workflow one at a time and check between steps what is going wrong.

If the step is a simple command like checking out a repo or `apt install`ing some dependencies I can just run the bash command myself, but when my steps are using a premade action like `actions/setup-python@v4` or `turtlebrowser/get-conan@main` is there a way to tell the runner "do the next step in the workflow file as if I wasn't here" or a way to say "do the `actions/setup-python@v4` action" or do I have to go read what those premade actions are doing and enter all the bash commands one line at a time?

I know you can use `touch continue` to get it to run all the steps to finish the workflow, but I want to just run one step at a time.

Comment: Anyone even have the same problem or am I the only one trying to do this? It might be that I'm just doing something stupid so if you have a totally different way of debugging GHA workflows that would be useful too!